# How can I tell the address of the remote server an app communicates to?

Tags: ios, network

I have installed an iPhone app from the AppStore that takes a phone number and searches an online database then returns a name that belongs to the entered phone number (and vice versa).

Is there a way for me to know what is the back-end server this app is talking to? (a hostname, or an IP address)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only applies to macOS and not to iOS:

You could use Wireshark or lsof which is already included in macOS.

With lsof you can type `lsof -i | grep -E "(LISTEN|ESTABLISHED)"` into your terminal and it will show you all connections that are actively communicating.

Edit: You could use a custom DNS like [pihole](https://pi-hole.net) to see which domains are requested by the app.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the app is an iPhone app. Is this method still valid in my case?

Comment: No for iOS, this approach will sadly not work.

Comment: No this won't work for iOS but you could use the method suggested in the edit.